# Como criar um objeto por meio de uma String?

Tags: java

Suponha que tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
public class ItemDePedido {

    private int qtde;
    private double subtotal;
    private Produto produto;
}
```

Na memória este objeto (já criado) é interpretado como :

> model.ItemDePedido@40c8f929

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Existe alguma forma de converter uma String com este valor, em um Objeto?

Comment: Desculpe, mas não entendi porque quer converter a string em objeto se ele já está criado. Não seria somente reusar o objeto? Ou precisa de outra instância desse objeto (clone)?

Comment: Exato. preciso de um clone desse objeto